# Cell selection style changing on second tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my table view I am setting the the selection style inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {

MyCell *aCell = (MyCell *)[iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath];
aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Now, the selection style changes on the second tap and not on the first tap. Once a cell is tapped then it works fine if you come back and select it again. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you post your code for the datasource delegate - `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  My guess is you need to call `reloadData` after changing the underlying model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* the reason for this is that the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method gets called when the cell **have already been** selected (surprise!). So the default selection style is applied **before** the method gets called first time, i.e. before you do your `aCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`. When the selection style was changed once, apparently it remains for subsequent calls (taps). To fix this, you have to set the selection style in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` methods, which are called before selecting the cell.